# Why MS SQL bigint type is implicitly mapped to float64 python type, and what is the best way to handle it?

Tags: sql-server, python, external-scripts

Python integer type has [unlimited precision](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) so it is more than capable to hold a bigint value of MS SQL (64 bit). Still it is [implicitly mapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/python/python-libraries-and-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15) to float64 python type, when passed to an external script.

This can cause serious calculation errors for large integers.

So why is it mapped to float64?

My guess is:

R was added before Python via the [Extensibility architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/concepts/extensibility-framework?view=sql-server-ver15) and it has fixed precision integers (32 bit). So it can't hold bigints. So perhaps this is a compatibility issue.

What is the best practice to ensure precise calculations?

Simple but working idea: pass bigints as string then parse them as int.

I know it has a slim chance to cause problem in practice, but still good to know.

## How can it be a problem:

I wrote a simple example to demonstrate how can it be a problem:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (
    big_integer BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO #test 
    (big_integer)
VALUES
    (36028797018963968),
    (36028797018963968 + 1);

EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script 
    @language = N'Python',
    @input_data_1 = N'SELECT big_integer FROM #test',
    @script = N'
print(InputDataSet.dtypes)
OutputDataSet = InputDataSet
'
```

Executing this code on SQL Server 2019 will give you the result of:

```
| | (No column name)  |
|---------------------|
|1| 36028797018963970 |
|2| 36028797018963970 |
```

and because of the `print(InputDataSet.dtypes)` statement we can see the following message:

```
...
STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
big_integer    float64
dtype: object
...
```

So we got a floating point rounding error. The value of this error for big enough integers is greater than 1, which is the root of this problem.

It is out of the scope of this question to teach floating point arithmetics, but I link some good materials if you don't understand what did happen:

[Simple example - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249467/what-is-a-simple-example-of-floating-point-rounding-error).

[Floating Point Numbers - Computerphile](https://youtu.be/PZRI1IfStY0)

[The IEEE 754 Format - Oxford](http://mathcenter.oxford.emory.edu/site/cs170/ieee754/)

I also share a small ipython sample if you want to experiment with this (which isn't a substitute of learning the theory behind this):

```
In [16]: import numpy as np

In [17]: a = 2**55

In [18]: a
Out[18]: 36028797018963968

In [19]: float(a) == float(a + 1)
Out[19]: True

In [20]: float(a)
Out[20]: 3.602879701896397e+16

In [21]: float(a + 1)
Out[21]: 3.602879701896397e+16

In [22]: np.nextafter(float(a), np.inf)
Out[22]: 3.6028797018963976e+16
```

## Note

To run my example T-SQL some conditions must be met:

- [Machine Learning Services must be installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/sql-machine-learning-services-windows-install?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [external scripts must be enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/external-scripts-enabled-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Privilege to execute external scripts must be granted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/security/user-permission?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [You must have SQL Server 2017 CTP 2.0 or later](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-python-in-sql-server-2017-to-obtain-advanced-data-analytics/)

Comment: Where in Python are you seeing this mapping?...it could be just an issue of whatever tool is auto-detecting the data type. Also wouldn't there be just the same precision with `float64` storing a `BIGINT`, since everything to the right of the decimal place would be 0s anyway?...I could be misremembering but I thought the issue with floats were approximations resulting from rounding on the right side of the decimal place.

Comment: @J.D. This not how exactly floating point conversion works I updated the question. I hope it will help to describe a problem a bit more

Comment: Nice update to your post, appreciate it. Looks like I need to brush up on my floats, I never use them so I couldn't remember exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write down the best solution what I found:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (
    big_integer BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO #test 
    (big_integer)
VALUES
    (36028797018963968),
    (36028797018963968 + 1);

CREATE TABLE #out (
    big_integer BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO #out
    EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script 
        @language = N'Python',
        @input_data_1 = N'SELECT CAST(big_integer AS VARCHAR(20)) AS big_integer FROM #test',
        @script = N'
import numpy as np
print(InputDataSet)
InputDataSet["big_integer"] = InputDataSet["big_integer"].astype(np.int64)
InputDataSet["big_integer"] = InputDataSet["big_integer"] + 1
InputDataSet["big_integer"] = InputDataSet["big_integer"].astype(str)
OutputDataSet = InputDataSet
';

SELECT big_integer FROM #out;
```

I did what I supposed in the question:

1. cast the `big_integer` column to `VARCHAR(20)` the maximum length of a string representation of 64 bit signed integer:

```
In [34]: len(str(-2**63))
Out[34]: 20

In [35]: len(str(2**63-1))
Out[35]: 19
```

2. cast it back to [numpy.int64 type](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html) in the external script.
3. made a simple calculation: incremented all values in the column
4. cast it back to string still in python. This step also necessary, because the implicit type conversion works both ways.
5. Inserted the values into the `big_integer` column of the `#out` table. Which also has a `BIGINT` type and the returned strings were implictly casted to `BIGINT`

## Note

It would be a rare event where you need to handle this problem. The integer value must be bigger than 2^52 so a distance between two float64 will be greater than 1.

```
In [50]: def float_distance(x):
    ...:     x_float = float(x)
    ...:     x_next_float = np.nextafter(x_float, np.inf)
    ...:     x_float_diff = x_next_float - x_float
    ...:     return(x, x_float, x_next_float, x_float_diff)

In [51]: float_distance(2**52)
Out[51]: (4503599627370496, 4503599627370496.0, 4503599627370497.0, 1.0)

In [52]: float_distance(2**53)
Out[52]: (9007199254740992, 9007199254740992.0, 9007199254740994.0, 2.0)
```

I guess this may occur if your store the results of high throughput scientific research in physics or in bioinformatics.